# How to launch and connect to running amazon windows instance using Amazon CLI( Powershell) erro:WinRM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i'm trying to connect to Amazon windows instance which is already running and also i'm trying to create instance through Amazon Powershell. I tried using the below Command to create

```
 Example:  aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-555555 --count 1 --key-name KEYNAME --subnet-id subnet-777777 --security-group-ids sg-5555566 --instance-type t2.medium
```

Its launching the instance but i really have no idea how to connect it.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> enable-psremoting
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> $cred = get-credential -username "Administrator" -message "password"
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> $sess = new-pssession -computername My IP4 address goes here -credential $cred -authentication default
new-pssession : [x.x.x.x] Connecting to remote server [x.x.x.x] failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the
request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or
the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the
TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:9
+ $sess = new-pssession -computername [x.x.x.x] -credential $cred - ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerNotTrusted,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I get shown the above error. Please assist me on how to connect to my instance. any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same ssh key-pem to which the instance was created ?

Comment: Yes i'm using the same ssh key-pem . I'm following this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html to connect to windows server 2016 instance through powershell. but i'm keep getting the below error:        
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server x.x.x.x failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer.

Comment: @SantiagoQuinteros Could you please help me with the AWS command to connect to the instance using amazon powershell